# How to use IF statement in a calculation in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I use following query to give me the earned commission of our sales agents.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT agent, 
    COUNT(*) as sales, 
        (4*(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Sales Sales2 
        WHERE Sales2.agent=Sales.agent AND finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND flow=117)) 
        / 
        (SELECT SUM(uren) FROM Uren WHERE datum BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND agent=Sales.agent) as sph   
    FROM Sales 
        WHERE finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-11-27 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND flow=117 
        GROUP BY agent ) r 
    ORDER BY sales * sph desc;
```

Now I want the output to be sorted by `(sales * sph * factor)`. Where factor is 10 if `sph > 1.5` and else 7.5.

Is it possible to implement this in the query. If yes how do I achieve this?

It would also be good if calculation would be done in the `SELECT` statement like `(sales * sph * factor) as commission` and then just use `SORT BY commission`.

I hope my question makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use condition in order by eg using a case when

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM  (
        SELECT agent, 
        COUNT(*) as sales, 
            (4*(SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM Sales Sales2 
            WHERE Sales2.agent=Sales.agent AND finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND flow=117)) 
            / 
            (SELECT SUM(uren) FROM Uren WHERE datum BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND agent=Sales.agent) as sph   
        FROM Sales 
            WHERE finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-11-27 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-27 23:59:59' AND flow=117 
            GROUP BY agent ) r 
        ORDER BY sales * sph  * (case when  sph > 1.5 then 10 else 7.5 end ) desc;
```